# How to loop through from a root web and all its subsites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I came across a issue that I need to solve. I want to loop through a root web and all its subsites, and want to set some properties

Comment: I have provided you the solution for the same but one correction you can not apply the same for picture library as picture library does not supports Content approval so if you have to apply the solution to some other type of list you can do so

Comment: thank you for the code but How I can set the properties of image lists in each webs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = SpSecurityHelper.GetElevatedSite(GetSiteCollection(properties)))
        {
            SPWebCollection siteWebs = oSPsite.AllWebs;
            foreach (SPWeb web in siteWebs)
            {
                try
                {
                    SPList list = null;
                    try
                    {
                        list = web.Lists["Images"];
                    }
                    catch { }

                    if (list != null)
                    {

                        list.EnableModeration = isEnabled == false ? false: true;
                        list.Update();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (web != null)
                        web.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev:2021"))
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    foreach (SPList list in oSPWeb.Lists)
                    {
                        if ( list.ContentTypes.Count > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (SPContentType contentType in list.ContentTypes)
                            {
                                if (contentType.Name == "Document")
                                {
                                    list.EnableModeration = true;
                                    list.Update();  
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(oSPWeb.Webs.Count > 0) 
                    recursivewebcheck(oSPWeb); 
                }
            }
        }



       static  void recursivewebcheck(SPWeb oSPWeb)
        {

            foreach (SPWeb web in oSPWeb.Webs)
            {
                foreach (SPList list in oSPWeb.Lists)
                {
                    if (list.ContentTypes.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (SPContentType contentType in list.ContentTypes)
                        {
                            if (contentType.Name == "Document")
                            {
                                list.EnableModeration = true;
                                list.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (web.Webs.Count > 0)
                {
                    recursivewebcheck(web);
                }
                web.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution is for document library and well tested

Comment: This is only looping through all lists in root web, isn't it?

Comment: no its looping through all sites present under a site collection

Comment: I am fairly new to sharepoint, so maybe I'm getting something wrong, but here is my understanding:
oSPsite.OpenWeb() opens the web corresponding to the SPSite constructor, in the sample code, that is the root web. And the code is getting oSPWeb.Lists, which is all lists in the root web. How are lists from other SPWeb being retrieved?

Comment: recursivewebcheck method takes care of tht